# How to make interplanetary communication infrastructure for aliens of Earth without knowledge of humans?

Tags: internal-consistency, planets, aliens

Plenty of aliens from various galaxies have managed to land on Earth without getting tracked on Radars or satellites. For now, as I want my story to stay undisclosed, please assume that aliens have powers to reshape themselves as humans (Just like "Men In Black" story). They have also blend in different communities in such an outstanding way that they were never discovered by humans as of yet.

Now, these aliens want to stay connected to their family and friends living in their respective planets. There is no interplanetary communication infrastructure available on Earth. Aliens on Earth therefore decides to create an interplanetary communication infrastructure which has following requirements:

1. The website or interface of connection which will be made. should appear in all major search engines including Google and Bing on Earth as well as some 'doogle' and 'ling' search engines of the respective planets of Aliens
2. Should not be, however, discovered by humans
3. The search engine bots should not read contents of this site except
   few meta data. Despite that, this website should come in top 10
   search results
4. This site should have some verification methods to identify that the one registering is genuinely not a human
5. Should not be tracked by any hackers, NASA, or any other space agencies.

**Questions**

1. Is it even possible to make such infrastructure (and that too without any single human's awareness)?
2. How will servers, databases and even satellites be made and launched to several light years away for establishing communication without getting tracked or knowledge of humans?
3. What should be the medium of communication which remains untracked?

Comment: Why does it have to show up on major search engines? Why is it even using the Internet?

Comment: Are you confusing *galaxy* with *planet*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aliens using our Internet, and publicly searchable no less, for their interplanetary communications network makes about as much sense as the aliens in Independence Day using our satellites... but that's ok, because I have a great answer.

## Make It An MMO.

Hide it in plain sight as a space themed MMO where you play as alien species. All the species and planets and tech in the game have real analogues and use all the same names. When two aliens are talking about intergalactic politics, any humans eavesdropping assume they're talking about the game. This works in game, and out of game.

Some players are humans, some players are aliens on Earth, some players are aliens not on Earth. Alien player accounts have a special flag that only other aliens can see. This flag is hidden with [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) as a combination of other normal player stats so even someone looking at the network protocol won't see an obvious flag. For example, it could be encoded as a combination of the player name and their avatar's physical features.

There's a real game there that humans can play if they like, but it's not very good. It's just there to provide a plausible front for having people playing and talking about the "game". Otherwise it looks like another generic, mediocre space MMO.

You can even have conventions about the game where players are encouraged to cos-play. It gives aliens an opportunity to take off their human costumes and be themselves for a while. Meanwhile, real alien news masquerades as NPC news in-game.

> *How will servers, databases and even satellites be made and launched to several light years away for establishing communication without getting tracked or knowledge of humans?*

## Start A Space Launch Company.

Once again, hide it in plain sight.

Tracking launches is easy. Even with fancy alien technology, all that energy being expended inside the atmosphere will generate a lot of heat and light that's going to get noticed. So cover it by starting a commercial space launch agency. You can even use conventional rockets.

Tracking stuff once it's in space is very hard, even in LEO. Space is really, really, really big and spacecraft are relatively small. You need to know where to look. Once your conventional rocket has reached orbit, it releases its conventional payload... and also its real payload of an interstellar communications relay which speeds off.

While they're at it, they also start an electric car company and solar power company to save the comfortable climate the humans are hell bent on modifying.

Comment: I may be missing something about the first option, as internet (specifically TCP/IP) cannot work beyond the Moon (not to mention that a latency of several years would be quite telling)

Comment: @SJuan76 if they use some strange alien interstellar communications array, then they might use ftl coms.

Comment: Did you really mean stenography or did you mean steganography? Steganography seems to match the description a bit better.

Comment: @SJuan76 Like I said at the start, I really don't understand the OP's scenario. I was going to have an answer explaining all the ways it made no sense, but then I came upon this idea and it was just too good. :) But on that note, [Vint Cerf has a plan for an Interplanetary Internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interplanetary_Internet).

Answer (score 2):

The aliens' first step is to infiltrate the NSA, the various military organizations and their equivalents around the world creating a top secret military base or bases with interplanetary communications facilities to communicate with their home systems.

If their communications medium is non-electromagnetic they won't be detected. This could be, for example, neutrinos or tachyons. If their spacecraft can come and go without being detected, putting a few undetectable satellites in space will be trivial.

If the alien technology is sufficiently advanced, humans won't even recognize what the devices they connect to the internet can do. Their servers and databases might be concealed as ordinary desktop PCs or laptops. This should make their ability to connect into telephone lines, optical cables or even wi-fi hot spots straight forward. There is no reason why they couldn't add their own nodes to the system in places where the usual telco technicians don't check. For example, under sections of sidewalks or roads.

The use of advanced encryption and verification systems will ensure only the aliens can use their internet. They could install their own software in the very systems used to monitor the internet, to block all NSA type of inceptions and online surveillance.

Essentially aliens who can arrive and depart Earth without being observed shouldn't have much trouble hi-jacking our normal communications systems for their own use.

Comment: The major problem here, from an information security perspective, is while we may not be able to read their encrypted traffic, we will see it on the network, wonder what the hell it is, and know who's sending it to who (or, at least, their IP addresses). Internet anonymity tools have a similar problem where if you can identify traffic from an anonymity tool you can investigate and block it.

Comment: @Schwern Good point. That's why the postulated alien software blocks the monitoring of internet traffic. Perhaps that wasn't made clear enough.

Comment: @a4android You can't block monitoring of Internet traffic anymore than you can block monitoring of highway traffic, just like cars have to travel down the road, the data has to travel down the lines and through switches and routers. It's not the NSA you have to worry about, it's the companies who physically own the lines especially someone like Comcast who regularly monitor their networks for anything that might look like IP infringing activity. Best you can do is hide it as something else fairly common like a VPN.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to question one is

**YES**

We have it today, it's called Tor.  Onion routing allows you to access services and data using Internet technology (TCP/IP and Web Browsers) without having direct access to the network it's on, and without malicious third parties being able to access your endpoints.  Note that this is assuming Tor Services, where the end application (the bridge to Alien Internet) is on the Tor network, and therefore traffic never leaves Tor.

You meet your Alien buddy at the Men In Black immigration center, and you are given a TOR onion address to the S-mail service that sends emails back to Planet Q.  You can use any computer with any web browser, install Tor, punch in that onion address, and use S-mail.

Yes, you will be emitting encrypted packets, but much of the data flowing on the internet these days is encrypted anyway, and Tor packets (which never leave the Tor network) look exactly like any other SSL traffic (Gmail, Amazon, online banking...).  The NSA might be interested, but without all the metadata they slurp up from the insecure Internet it'll be nearly impossible for them to snoop your alien data.

The tech is here today;  it's how Snoden leaked stuff FROM THE NSA.  If it's good enough to slip PRISM to the media, it's good enough to send vacation photos to Planet Q.

Tor hidden services can have a public internet component as well. In that case, the aliens can use the "Darmok" code from Star Trek, TNG. Google Searches for Flubba and President Goo at the River Bloob would be pure nonsense to Humans, but could lead to a historical page listing on pastebin or Fanfiction.net that contains information about getting in contact with an embassy, based on historical context relevant only to aliens. But you can't have both secure communications and an open channel.  You simply cannot.  Unless you're willing to cheat.

See, there's one method for two parties to share an encryption key without meeting each other face to face:  public key cryptography.  This depends on super advanced maths on prime numbers that allow two parties to agree on a key while a middleman eavesdropping lacks some data required to reconstruct it.  So, if you're willing to wave your hands a bit, and the aliens are allowed to have advanced tech in their possession, they could have equipment that allows them to calculate HUGE prime numbers, vastly bigger than anything the NSA can do, and use those as part of an RSA or DF key exchange.

Every other encryption system requires that some pre-arranged piece of data be shared publicly, and that requires a face to face meeting.

Comment: Woah..Had never heard about Tor...+1 for introducing it here..Really interesting

Comment: Good point on how to use the Internet for their own purposes, but this will *not* show up publicly or on Google searches etc. as the OP asked.  They need to be given the secret address, as you explain.

Comment: Unfortunately, OP's request is mutually exclusive, as other comments have stated, @JDlugosz.  Tor hidden services **can** have a public internet component as well.  In that case, the aliens can use the "Darmok" code from Star Trek, TNG.  Google Searches for Flubba and President Goo at the River Bloob would be pure nonsense to Humans, but could lead to a historical page listing on pastebin or Fanfiction.net that contains information about getting in contact with an embassy, based on historical context relevant only to aliens.

But you can't have both secure communications and an open channel.

Comment: You should add that to your answer.

Comment: Updates with more thoughts about communication in the clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to question one is a clear

## No

Searching on the internet is big business and there is a constant race between [specialists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) who want to boost the "google rank" of a site and search engine providers who want to boost the value and revenue stream of their company, mostly through targeted advertising.

So when a "site out of nowhere" shows up high on google for commercially valuable keywords, there are humans who will wonder, and who will try to get their site higher at the expense of the weird site. If the aliens scheme to keep their site up with no apparent reason will make those very smart people wonder.

Your question two is kind of rendundant. Why should the aliens worry about launching payloads to space if they arrived from space in a way that was not tracked? That almost certainly implies stealthy "UFOs" or the like. If not, the answer to question two would be another

## No

If you look at human deep space activity, look at [Voyager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_program#Voyager_Interstellar_Mission). We cannot launch anything that will travel lightyears anytime soon, and if we could launch it we could not communicate with it.

Regarding the third question, any sufficiently encrypted data network would raise the attention of people like the NSA, simply because they cannot read it.